# Permanently replace windows 7 autoplay with open folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, autoplay

How do I disable windows from scanning content in external drive and start the explorer right away? From my experience, as far as "Use Autoplay" is ticked, windows has to scan the drive for content in case if it matches any of the criterias, and then after 10 seconds, it opens the explorer window.

If I disable the autorun, can I create a (lightweight) script (like autohotkey) to open windows explorer when ever new drive is detected.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Start then Control Panel and click on Autoplay you can change the default behavior for whatever type of Media you insert.

So in theory changing all of these to 'Open Folder to view in Explorer' should give you your required behavior.

Comment: thanks for replying back, even I thought so, but even after setting everything to open folder, http://i.stack.imgur.com/qkk8I.png, I still get the autoplay window, which opens the folder after 10 seconds of scanning http://i.stack.imgur.com/XXheq.png

Comment: No problem will try to get this sorted for you, what exactly is that you have inserted a USB stick or CD or external Hard Drive, etc.?